# white-space: pre-wrap causes big line spacing

Tags: css, tabulator

I reworked [a table in LibreOffice's wiki](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/index.php?title=Language/Support&oldid=681496) to use [Tabulator.js](https://tabulator.info/). Tabulator loads the data from the HTML table in this case. I used a custom formatter for some columns so they get `white-space: pre-wrap`.

In the cells of the last column, Additional language extensions, you can see big line spacing for no good reason (tested in FF and Chromium). I can't figure out why `white-space: pre-wrap` is causing this (uncheck the rule for a cell element and see the spacing go away). There is no such spacing in the first 3 columns that also have the rule.

[Source of the Tabulator wiki widget](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/index.php?title=Widget:LanguageTable&oldid=681523&action=edit).

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/21849374)
It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `white-space: normal` (or remove `white-space: nowrap` from the parent elements.)

[MDN definition of `pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#values)

> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

What this means is all of the line breaks in your HTML is preserved and rendered on screen.

Minimal example of your code using `white-space: pre-wrap`

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 208px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p><b> Spell check dictionaries</b>
</p>
<ul><li>Akan spell-check dictionary</li>
<li>Akan spell-check dictionary (AOO website)</li></ul>
</div>
```

Example using `white-space: normal` instead

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 208px;
  white-space: normal;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p><b> Spell check dictionaries</b>
</p>
<ul><li>Akan spell-check dictionary</li>
<li>Akan spell-check dictionary (AOO website)</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I must have mistakenly thought/seen some problem when using normal, but it's indeed fine.